# Python requests stop redirects does not work

Tags: python, redirect, python-requests

I want to access the content of a web page, but I'm being redirected to another page even though I've set allow_redirects to False in my requests call. Here's an example code snippet:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent} # assume I inserted my user agent here
URL = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73909641/program-is-about-space-utilisation-i-am-getting-error-72g-value-too-great-for"
html_content = requests.get(URL, allow_redirects=False, headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content.content, "html.parser")
```

When I run this code, I don't get any content from the web page. However, if I set allow_redirects to True, I'm redirected to this URL: [Convert between byte count and "human-readable" string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37015073/convert-between-byte-count-and-human-readable-string).

Comment: Yes, oh okay, I need to log in first then

Comment: Why are you doing this particularly? Are you aware that [so] has [Data dumps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19579/where-are-the-stack-exchange-data-dumps)? Or that it has an [API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs)? Why insist on scraping data that is readily available?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Http Redirection code 3XX in python requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22150023/http-redirection-code-3xx-in-python-requests) Tl;dr you misunderstand how `allow_redirects` works, it can't prevent the server from sending redirects to you, all it does is that it stops `requests` from following the redirect.

Comment: Actually, there are rate limits for API and it is incredibly slow to download from archieve.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to log in to get to the *original* SO question because

> anonymous users get automatically redirected to the duplicate target when trying to access questions closed as duplicates with no answers

[The relevant Meta Post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285854/6106791), which is a duplicate itself of [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271077/why-do-dupe-questions-automatically-redirect-when-logged-out).

You can replicate this switching to Private Mode in your browser and then opening this link:

[Program is about space utilisation. i am getting error : 72G value too great for base (error token is "72")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73909641/program-is-about-space-utilisation-i-am-getting-error-72g-value-too-great-for)

You should get redirected to [Convert between byte count and "human-readable" string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37015073/convert-between-byte-count-and-human-readable-string)

EDIT:

You can turn off this behaviour and get to the original post with `rquests` by appending the URL with:

```
?noredirect=1
```

Here's an example:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36",
}

URL = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73909641/program-is-about-space-utilisation-i-am-getting-error-72g-value-too-great-for?noredirect=1"
html_content = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content.content, "html.parser").select_one("title")
print(soup)
```

Output:

```
<title>linux - Program is about space utilisation. i am getting error : 72G value too great for base (error token is "72") - Stack Overflow</title>
```

Comment: You don't need to login. `?noredirect=1` would get you a duplicate post even as an anonymous user.